# react-native link only for one project (Android or iOS)

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-linking

I want to link only one of my project (Android or iOS) with the npm package.  Is there any way to do it?

Comment: If you're using `git`, there's a simple workaround. Just link it, then checkout all the ios files that were changed `git checkout ios/*`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can choose to link libraries for only a certain platform by doing:

For Android: `react-native link (your_library_name_here) --platforms android`

For iOS: `react-native link (your_library_name_here) --platforms ios`

Comment: Clearly this should be the accepted answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

**if react-native < 60**

1. rename platforms ( iOS or Android) that you don't want to link.
2. run `react-native link your-library-js-package-name`.
3. rename platforms to the original name.

.

**react-native >= 60**

because the new react-native versions have some auto-linking feature you should tell the react-native CLI to do not link your library:

1. create a `react-native.config.js` file in the root of your project.
2. add some config like this

   ```
   module.exports = {
     dependencies: {
       'your-library-js-package-name': {
            platforms: {
              android: null, // assign null to disable autolinking
              ios: // assign null to disable autolinking or remove the 
                   ios key to let do the default linking
           },
       },

     },
   };
   ```

check this for more info [docs](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/autolinking.md)

Comment: This not always work, I rename my folder to `rename_ios` and still make the linking

Comment: @Juan P. Ortiz, react native 60 and later have an auto-linking feature so this solution will not work for you if you use auto-linking.

Answer (score 2):

When you run react-native link, it will link to required platform automatically.

If Module/dependency is required for iOS/Android only then will link to iOS/Android only.

If for both then linking will be for both.

And you can link to a platform manually as well.

Comment: Yes, but what if I don't want that module on iOS. I can manually link it on Android, right?

Comment: So that's what I want from react-native link, if it has any way to do it.

Comment: As of now there is no way from react-native link

Comment: was above link helpful?